# Finding a maximum count iterated over values in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking for help with MySQL Query.

I have a table that looks like this (but it goes on for many more rows with many different id values and years):

```
from_museum_id  to_museum_id    piece_id    year
1               4               4           2010
1               4               5           2010
1               4               32          2010
1               4               18          2013
1               4               18          2013
1               4               18          2014
1               4               18          2015
2               4               12          2015
2               4               7           2015
2               4               6           2015
2               4               33          2015
2               4               12          2017
2               4               6           2017
```

I have a query written for a relevant result set I am trying to find:

```
SELECT m.from_museum_id, m.year, COUNT(*) AS number_loaned
FROM museum_loan m
GROUP BY m.from_museum_id, m.year
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Which gives me result set:

```
from_museum_id  year    number_loaned
1               2013    2
1               2010    3
2               2017    2   
2               2015    4
```

But my issue is that I only need the year in which the number loaned was maximum like this:

```
from_museum_id  year    number_loaned
1               2010    3
2               2015    4
```

I have tried implementing a sub query in my HAVING statement which is trying to compare COUNT(*) to it's MAX to no avail. I keep getting only the single row where number loaned is maximum overall resulting in this:

```
from_museum_id  year    number_loaned
2               2015    4
```

This table is pretty big and there will be many from_museum_id to consider so any tricks with ORDER BY and LIMIT won't do it for me.

I've searched around for an hour but perhaps my novice SQL skills are preventing me from understanding how to solve this (if only it was in Python/R, it would be so easy!), even though there may be an answer somewhere out there applicable to this case.

I appreciate the advice.

Comment: This should be solvable using a subquery/derived table. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

Comment: I tried something like this but once again it only shows me one row where the museum & year had the most number_loaned as opposed to the most number loaned for each museum & year. I tried adding this to my HAVING clause:

`AND COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(cnt) 
                              FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
                                           FROM museum_loan m
                      GROUP BY m.from_museum_id, m.year) sub);`

Comment: What MySQL version do you use? `SELECT VERSION()` And can you also post the table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE museum_loan `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are looking for is:

```
SELECT m.from_museum_id, m.year,
       COUNT(*) AS number_loaned
FROM museum_loan m
GROUP BY m.from_museum_id, m.year
HAVING m.year = (SELECT m2.year
                 FROM museum_loan m2
                 WHERE m2.from_museum_id = m.from_museum_id
                 GROUP BY m2.year
                 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                 LIMIT 1
                );
```

You can also use the `GROUP_CONCAT()`/`SUBSTRING_INDEX()` hack:

```
SELECT my.from_museum_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(year ORDER BY number_loaned DESC) as year,
       MAX(number_loaned) as number_loaned
FROM (SELECT m.from_museum_id, m.year,
             COUNT(*) AS number_loaned
      FROM museum_loan m
      GROUP BY m.from_museum_id, m.year
     ) my
GROUP BY my.from_museum_id;
```

Comment: you forgot COUNT(*) > 1 in your HAVING statement but that was an easy addition, and other than that these queries have been elegant and concise. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if you are using MYSQL V8 & above:

```
WITH temp 
     AS (SELECT m.from_museum_id, 
                m.year, 
                Count(from_museum_id) AS number_loaned 
         FROM   museum_loan m 
         GROUP  BY m.from_museum_id, 
                   m.year 
         HAVING Count(from_museum_id) > 0) 
SELECT from_museum_id, 
       year, 
       number_loaned 
FROM   temp t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT from_museum_id, 
                          Max(number_loaned) AS number_loaned 
                   FROM   temp 
                   GROUP  BY from_museum_id) t2 
               ON t1.from_museum_id = t2.from_museum_id 
                  AND t1.number_loaned = t2.number_loaned;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to query the result of your original query using it as derived table:

`SELECT m_id, year, MAX(number_loaned) FROM (SELECT m.from_museum_id AS m_id, m.year AS year, COUNT(*) AS number_loaned FROM museum_loan m GROUP BY m.from_museum_id, m.year HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 
GROUP BY m_id;`

Comment: you mist a alias for the derived table if you indent or format your SQL query you would have seen it. SQL is meant to be readable, understandable and maintainable a SQL one liner is non of that. Also your query is not ANSI SQL and misusing MysQL's GROUP BY feature meaning it will fail on MySQL servers with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode... see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25f61c/24

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate a dense rank function

```
SELECT m.from_museum_id, m.year, COUNT(*) AS number_loaned,
        if(m.from_museum_id <> @p, @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
         @p:=m.from_museum_id p
FROM t m
cross join (select @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
GROUP BY m.from_museum_id, m.year
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 and rn = 1
order by m.from_museum_id, count(*) desc

+----------------+------+---------------+------+------+
| from_museum_id | year | number_loaned | rn   | p    |
+----------------+------+---------------+------+------+
|              1 | 2010 |             3 |    1 |    1 |
|              2 | 2015 |             4 |    1 |    2 |
+----------------+------+---------------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```